# Jquery disable dragging left only

Tags: jquery

I have got this jquery

```
        $(".tagdiv").draggable({
                 drag: function(e, ui) {}
            });
        $(".tagdiv").on('drag',function(e,ui){
            var lft=parseInt($(this).css('left'));
            var mlft=parseInt($(this).css('margin-left'));
            if (lft==mlft-(mlft*2))  {
                $(this).trigger("mouseup").draggable('disable');
            }
        });
```

When user drags `tagdiv` and reaches `lft==mlft-(mlft*2)` dragging disables and he can't drag anywhere.But i want him to be able to drag anywhere instead of left`

Answer (score 0):

> From [containment](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment) : you may use an array defining a bounding box in the form [ x1, y1, x2, y2 ]

So you may write something like:

```js
$(function () {
  var mlft = parseInt($(".tagdiv").css('margin-left'));
  var mrgt = $(document).width() - $(".tagdiv").outerWidth() - mlft;

  $(".tagdiv").draggable({
    containment: [mlft, 0, mrgt, $(document).outerHeight()]
  });
});
```

```css
.tagdiv {
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content tagdiv">
    <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
```

Instead, if you need to fix your code, you may use:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

instead of:

```
$(this).trigger("mouseup").draggable('disable');
```

Moreover use :

```
ui.offset.left
```

to get left offset position instead of:

```
$(this).css('left')
```

The snippet:

```js
$(function () {
  $(".tagdiv").draggable({
    drag: function( event, ui ) {
      var lft = ui.offset.left;
      var mlft = parseInt($(this).css('margin-left'));
      if (lft<=mlft-(mlft*2))  {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.tagdiv {
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin-left: 150px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content tagdiv">
    <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
```